# How to echo out dynamic checkboxes?

Tags: php

I have problems displaying my checkboxes. Can anyone please help? I search the solution online and I tried the codes but it doesn't work.

Here is my codes

```
<?php
include "mysqli.connect.php";
// Make a MySQL Connection
$retrieveflavor = "SELECT * FROM flavor"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($retrieveflavor);  
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    //echo "<input type='checkbox' name='candyFlavors[]' value=".$row['flavorname']."/>";
    //echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"candyFlavors[]\" value=\"$row[flavorname]\">";
    //echo "<input name=\"candyFlavors[]\" type='checkbox' value='"$row[flavorname]"'/>";
    echo "<td><img src=".$row['image']." width='240px' height='190px'></td>";
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"candyFlavors[]\" value=\"$row[flavorname]\">";
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the problem, and what are you expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be like this.

```
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"candyFlavors[]\" value=\"".$row['flavorname']."\">";
```

You missed single quote in `$row[flavorname]`

Comment: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING on line 351 - it shows me this error.

Comment: You missed the escape sequence character \ in  the previous line for src=".$row['image'].". Add it and check.

Comment: I have found your problem. Edited my answer. Please try it now.

Comment: Hi. It still doesn't display.

Comment: Is image displayed correctly? Can you update your code with current code?

Answer (score 1):

```
  echo '<input type="checkbox" name="candyFlavors[]" value="'.$row['flavorname'].'">';
```

Try this